# Size of data block in avro is larger than the maximum allowed value 16777216

Tags: hive, google-bigquery, avro

I am trying to load Avro data into Bigquery.So i converted ORC data into AVRO by running INSERT OVERWRITE COMMAND in hive.When i try to load data in Bigquery using bq command line tool, I am getting this error:-

> "message": "Error while reading data, error message: Avro parsing error in position 397707. Size of data block 17378680 is larger than the maximum allowed value 16777216."

Is there any way i can increase this data block size.I couldn't find anything related to this.

Below is the command that i am trying to use to load data.

```
bq load --source_format=AVRO dataset.table gs://********/gold/offers/hive/gold_hctc_ofr_txt/ingestion_time=20180305/000000_0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BQ Load error : Avro parsing error in position 893786302. Size of data block 27406834 is larger than the maximum allowed value 16777216](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611127/bq-load-error-avro-parsing-error-in-position-893786302-size-of-data-block-274)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are actually getting bumped due to BigQuery’s block size limit as defined in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs). You can check on the **Row and cell size limits** section where it is mentioned that Avro’s block size is 16MB.

Comment: By compressing the data, Can i achieve this?

Comment: If you can reduce the block size [by compression](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#loading_compressed_and_uncompressed_data), you should be able to achieve this. Currently, when loading data into BigQuery _gzip_ is the only supported file compression type. However, keep in mind that data compression can have some negative impact on performance also.

Comment: I am dealing with AVRO data so compressed data is not allowed in case of AVRO.If i can compress block size then only its possible.I don't now any properties yet.If you have any Please share with me.

Comment: @VishwanathSharma, according to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#avro_compression) `compressed Avro files are not supported, but compressed data blocks are`, which is why I asked to reduce **data blocks**.You can use DEFLATE or Snappy codecs for compression as those are the only ones supported by BigQuery. You can check [this document](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.avro.file.CodecFactory)  for sample source code which I found on the internet.

Comment: @Tahar, I tried it using Table property (avro.codec='deflate') in hive table but still i am not able to achieve it.Snappy is gonna increase the size as compare to deflate.

Comment: @VishwanathSharma, by _not able to achieve it_ - if you mean the compression is not enough then currently these are the [compression types supported in BigQuey exports](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#bigquery) which have been added very recently _(2018-03-14)_. If you are searching for procedure of compression, I would suggest to post that as a separate question.